# Expression for liking a thing after discussing about it

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an expression for this example situation?

When you've watched a movie but donot carry much of an opinion about it. But after discussing with someone you feel that it was not bad after all. After further discussion (with others), it slowly grows(?) on you until you feel that its the best movie you've ever watched.

Comment: What you said, "it grows on you", is a common phrase.  "I didn't like it at first, but it has really grown on me".

Comment: You can *come round* to their point of view (i.e. change your opinion).

Comment: You can also *take a shine to* something (not just people).

Comment: @Mick Its not the case that their opinion is influencing me. Like its one sided. I keep telling them about the movie and I feel that it I liked it more after telling someone about it than before.

Comment: Maybe you *talked yourself round* to liking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The more I talked about the movie, the more I **came to appreciate**
> its greatness.
>
> The more I talked about the movie, the more it's greatness
> **grew on me**.

From The Free Dictionary:

> [**appreciate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appreciate): to
> recognize the quality, significance, or magnitude of
>
> [**grow on**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grow+on): to become
> increasingly liked or appreciated by you

Comment: I thought about _appreciate_ too but wasn't quite sure how to put it in an answer. +1. Oops, my daily vote limit is breached. Will have to wait to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You *warm* to the movie.  You warm to the favorable point of view.  You have warmed to the movie.  That is the same thing as the movie growing on you, the only difference is the point of view.

Dictionary.com:

To warm (without an object:

21.
to become ardent, enthusiastic, animated, etc. (often followed by up or to):
The speaker quickly warmed to her subject.

22.
to grow kindly, friendly, or sympathetically disposed (often followed by to or toward):
My heart warms toward him.